# R Loop: Perform a spearman correlation for Every 12 Rows

Tags: r

I have a matrix which contains 984 rows and 2 columns (M and B), I want to do a spearman correlation of the 2 columns for every 12 rows, so in total 82 correlation. This is what I have

```
df ->read(......)
M = df$M
B = df$B

cnt <- 0
for (i in seq(1, nrow(df), by = 12)) {
M = df$[M,cnt]
B = df$[B, cnt]
resultM-B = cor(M, B, method = "spearman")
cat("Spearman correlation MB", resultM-B,"\n")
cnt <- cnt + 12
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you provide a real, representative example dataset, in plain text format. Something like `dput(head(df, 24))` would do, that would give us two sets of 12 rows to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a job for `by`

Make up an indexing factor

```
idx <- ceiling((1:nrow(df))/12)
```

Then tell `by` to use that as a guide:

```
res <- by(df, idx, function(x){cor(x$M, x$B, method ="spearman")})
```

Comment: Thanks this help a lot

Answer (score 1):

For dummy data with 24 rows, you may try

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  M = rnorm(24, 1, 1),
  B = rnorm(24, 1, 5)
)

cnt <- 12
res <- c()
for (i in seq(1, nrow(df1), by = 12)){
  M1 <- df1$M[i:cnt]
  B1 <- df1$B[i:cnt]
  res_MB <- cor(M1, B1, method = "spearman")
  res <- c(res, res_MB)
  cnt <- cnt + 12
}
res
[1] -0.4755245 -0.2727273
```

Comment: Thanks this help a lot